# Unable to update my database schema in Symfony getting error in FOSUser Bundle

Tags: entity-framework, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

I am Downloading `FOSUserBundle` in Symfony Framework using composer and at the time of Update your database schema I am facing this error.

> "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\FOSUserTry\src\AppBundle\Entity\User.php on line 13".

I have also attached screenshot below.

**User.php**

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}
}
```

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Isn't it "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser"?

Comment: Sir how can we make and call "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" class.

Comment: I changed "use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;" to "use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;" Now "Database schema updated successfully! "1" query was executed" Its working

Comment: Finally I created my FOSUser Bundle in Symfony 3. Thanks all

Comment: This was actually in the docs for using this API.